# What is the difference between L2VPN and EoMPLS?

Tags: mpls, l2vpn

Quick terminology question:

It appears as though L2VPN describes a group of technologies. Ethernet over Multiprotocol Label Switching (EoMPLS) is one of these technologies.  VPLS and Pseudowire are others.

If this is correct, it's not possible to configure L2VPNs, per se.  Instead, we configure, for instance EoMPLS which achieves a L2VPN.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. L2VPN is the technology, and VPLS and VPWS are services configured using that technology. When someone talks about configuring an L2VPN, they could be talking about configuring any of those services.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/wg/l2vpn/about/
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4664